# Recursion in shared pointers while variable is defined in the class

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a simple question. I have a LinkList class and root is initiated inside the class.

```
class LinkList {

     struct node {
        int data;
        shared_ptr<node> next;
    };

    shared_ptr<node> root;

    public:
       void insert(int data);
       void remove(int data);
       void print();
       int length();
       bool search_recursive(int data);
       bool search_recursiveUtil(shared_ptr<node> p, int data);
  }
```

Ideally I wanted to implement a recursive function to search for a node. Now I implemented in the following way:

```
bool LinkList::search_recursiveUtil(shared_ptr<node> p, int data){

     if(p == nullptr){
        return false;
     }

     if(p->data == data){
        return true;
     }

     return search_recursiveUtil(p->next, data);

}

bool LinkList::search_recursive(int data){

     shared_ptr<node> p = root;
     return search_recursiveUtil(p, data);
}
```

Now clearly you can see that since I do not want root to reach at the end of the linked list as other functions might use this head pointer to do something, I am taking a shared pointer P and traversing it. Now I want to have p to be pass to the "search_recursive" function but since it doesn't take shared_ptr argument so I had to take support of a "search_recursiveUtil" function.

My question is it is right way to approach? How can i implement this without having util function support?

Comment: Why recursively? There is very little benefit to a recursive solution. It's incredibly space inefficient.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but I'd implement it in an iterative fashion, which would be much more efficient.

Comment: Also note that passing a shared pointer by value has quite some overhead compared to pay by const red (of course the semantics are different, but in your case both would work)

Comment: I know recursion is not an efficient way but I wanted to try that out.

Comment: What is an iterative way? Can you please explain or perhaps a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the consideration on why using a recursive search (the will soon result in a stack overflow as soon as the list becomes big enough) instead of a iterating one, since pointers are passed by value, there is no need of `p`: just call `return search_recursiveUtil(root, data)`. Your reasoning abut root to reach the end of the list is a misconception.

The use of an xUtil function taking a positional parameter not required when calling the search from outside can be a good idea, just make it private to the class, so that -from outside- your interface will be just the `search_recursive` function.

Also, declare both the functions `const`, since they are not supposed to modify the data.

An alternative can be place the "Util" function as a node member, so that you can do

```
bool LinkList::node::search_recursiveUtil(int src_data){

     if(data == src_data)
        return true;

     if(pnext == nullptr)
        return false;

     return pnext->search_recursiveUtil(src_data);

}
```

called as

```
bool LinkList::search_recursive(int data){

     root->search_recursiveUtil(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Specially about the misconception.

Comment: Can you please explain these lines more? "The use of an xUtil function taking a positional parameter not required when calling the search from outside can be a good idea, just make it private to the class, so that -from outside- your interface will be just the search_recursive function.

Also, declare both the functions const, since they are not supposed to modify the data.

An alternative can be place the "Util" function as a node member, so that you can do

"

Comment: Ok, so now I got it. If I make a const function then it wouldnt modify the objects it is called upon and the code is working fine :) Thank you Emilio.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, that's exactly the way to go:
You have your interface function with the necessary parameters that calls an internal function with the required parameters. This way you keep your `root` member variable hidden. You could/should even declare your util member function private.